# Inline pre formatting?

Tags: html, wordpress

This should be easy points as I forgot how and can't find it on Google.

How do I accomplish something like this:

Blah Blah Blah `some code` Blah Blah

in wordpress? `pre` doesn't work as it will give a line break.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

<tt>text</tt> gives `text`

Wait... Wordpress?  What HTML tags does it support?

Comment: I'm not sure how the OP is writing this (either via HTML or the WYSIWYG interface), but Wordpress supports HTML.

Comment: `<tt>` is not supported in HTML5, use CSS or `<code>` instead.

Comment: The problem with this solution is when the preformatted text contains control character such as `<` it will be treated as tags unless you escape it manually

Answer (score 61):

It may be better to use `<code>` than `<pre>` to display inline code, for two reasons:

- it's treated as inline
- the semantics of `<code>` are a much better match than `<pre>`

But definitely use CSS classes (as @Blender points out).

There's a caveat: `<code>` doesn't escape `<>` brackets, so if you want to display HTML then you have to manually escape brackets as `&lt;` and `&gt;`. (which you should really do anyway; tags in HTML really should be clearly distinguished from data)

Comment: Another caveat: `<code>` collapses whitespace, which has bitten me before when I'm trying to discuss significant whitespace in a string with people.

Comment: @Andy I wonder if you could fix that with `white-space: pre;`?

Comment: Probably, I recently had to use that on a read-only textarea for the first time

Answer (score 15):

You can have an inline `<pre>` by adding some custom CSS to your theme's stylesheet:

```
pre.inline {
   display: inline;
}
```

Now, when you write:

```
I am some <pre class="inline">code, see?</pre> Foo.
```

It shows up like this:

> I am some `code, see?` Foo.

Comment: Nice solution but only works for self-hosted wordpress, not wordpress.com (unless on premium upgrade)

Comment: @gerrytan what about `<pre style="display: inline;">`?

Answer (score 0):

In this case is better to use `<code>`, it has a more semantic html syntax and any css workaround won't be needed to make it inline

```css
p {
  font-family: sans-serif
}

code {
  background: #c7c7c7;
  padding: .1rem .2rem;
  border-radius: .2rem;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Some text <code>some code</code> some text 
</p>
```